# How to collect order lines per group (using collect_list)?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DF as a flattened order line with columns as:

```
orderId (String), orderLine (struct)

1,  {"sequence":1,"productId":11111111,"productName":"Blah","quantity":1,"unitPrice":{"net":65},"totalPrice":{"gross":67.84,"net":65,"tax":2.84}}

1,  {"sequence":2,"productId":22222222,"productName":"Blah2","quantity":1,"unitPrice":{"net":100},"totalPrice":{"gross":104.38,"net":100,"tax":4.38}}
```

What is the most efficient way to generate a dataframe from this that is:

```
orderId (string), orderLines (Array of orderLine Struct)
```

Essentially grouping/collecting the individual lines structs for a given order into an array of line items - in this example orderLines would have the 2 orderLine items as part of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `groupBy` and `collect_list` function as follows:

```
orders.groupBy("orderId").agg(collect_list("orderLine"))
```

See [Dataset](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset) (for `groupBy`) and [functions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) object (for `collect_list` function).

Comment: Legend yet again this worked!  You are very helpful thanks Jacek.

Comment: I also have csv headers with spaces and trying to get a select experssion (using expr not selectExpr) to evaluate but errors (simple experssion really but not sure if the backticks are causing the issue?   expr("""CASE WHEN `Created By` = "x" THEN "y" ELSE  "z" END""").alias("a") - any ideas?

Comment: Could you please ask another question? I'd appreciate.

Comment: Got it working was a typo...once again thanks heaps!  If you could help on [linl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43963273/spark-dataframe-generate-an-array-of-tuple-from-a-map-type) that would be great too.  Im just finding my feet with Spark so appreciate your help alot!